# ')' or <expression> expected, got '-' spring boot sql command in jpa

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use sql command in spring boot jpa.

here is my code.
I want to delete all access token out of date(over 30 minutes).
the above one is working great. but when I use the sql command in Query annotation.
it reports

```
')' or <expression> expected, got '-'
```

on the minus operator below.

```
@Repository
public interface AccessTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<AccessToken, Long> {
  void deleteAllByUpdateTimeBefore(LocalDateTime updateTime_date);

    @Modifying
    @Query(
        "DELETE FROM AccessToken token WHERE token.updateTime < current_timestamp - INTERVAL 30
   MINUTE")
    AccessToken deleteByUpdateTime(LocalDateTime updateTime_date);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are writing SQL where you should write JPQL (or tell the framework that it is native SQL). ALso it won't return anything so the method needs to be `void` or return an `int` to get the number of rows deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will search JPQL and native SQL~